# Using VB.net how to use the second row as header in spredsheets

Tags: vb.net, excel, spreadsheet

I'd like to use the headings that I create in a spreadsheet as a key when writing data using vb.net.

I can use `xlSheet.Cells(2, 2)` but would like to use the heading I create for example:

```
ClientName   ClientNumber
```

So the code could read like:

```
xlSheet.Cells(2, "ClientName")
```

But i'm not sure how to code to use the second row as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just determine the column ordinal, then set a variable to point there?

For example:

```
Dim ClientName as integer
ClientName = 2
```

now you can use your variable

```
xlSheet.Cells(2,ClientName)
```

let me know if I misunderstand your question!

Comment: That may work, but is there way not having to declare all the variables. I may have 20 Headings would i need to declare a variable for each one?